# Error when trying to use REST API to connect to PayPal SandBox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to connect to the PayPal REST API. This is a Nim program that uses httpclient, but there's nothing specific to Nim since this is just a REST API.

The error I get is:

```
Error: unhandled exception: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [SslError]
```

I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.1m on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

> certificate verify failed

Your environment is not able to verify the SSL/TLS certificate currently used by paypal.com servers.

Update your root certificate authority bundle that's used to trust the signers of TLS certificates; [you can download a current one here](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html).

If you don't know where to put it, try `openssl version -d`

Comment: There are only some .cnf files in the directory printed by ```openssl version -d```. I added the certificate file downloaded from the link you gave, but it made no difference.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+update+trusted+root+certificate+authority